# 5 Hours (at least) to spend in BKK Suvarnabhumi or what else?

Tags: airports, thailand, bangkok, bkk

I'm travelling from Munich to Bangkok via Muscat at the end of September (economy class, so no lounge available). The Airport in which I'll land will be the Suvarnabhumi International Airport and the local time will be 8.00.

My parents will be flying with a different plane, which will land at the same airport at 13.00.
Provided that we already reserved our hotel in BKK and I asked if I could do an early check-in, to which they replied that I had to pay a night more (didn't expect that from a 5 stars hotel), I see myself bored as hell, sweat-stinky (apparently there's no possibility to take a shower in that airport), waiting on a bench with all my (heavy) stuff around. I would very much like to avoid that.
What are my best options (money/time/relax-wise)?

- Could I do anything decent enough to spend a couple of hours in the airport (possibly having my baggage stored anywhere?
- Should I go to the hotel and try to see if they can make me check-in anyway (and try not to pay more)?
- Should I surrender to the hotel's policy and have my room ready for me by paying a night more?
- Should I go to the hotel, store my things and go out strolling a bit (with jet-lag, without shower and so on...)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes there is baggage storage at Suvarnabhumi Airport, on the arrivals floor near door 3.  So you could get rid of your bags for a while, go enjoy a coffee or meal at one of the restaurants on level 3, then meet your parents when they arrive.

Or you could head for the hotel and see what the possibilities are.  They may be able to check you in early or if not they will likely be able to hold your bags until the room is ready and you can wander around the area for a while (best way to get over jetlag, walking around in the daylight).

The reason they told you they would charge you to reserve the room for early check in, because in order for you to have it at 8 am, they have to keep it empty the night before and therefore they lose the potential revenue for that room that night.  And five star hotels are just as revenue conscious as a one star hotel.

But if you just show up in the morning and if the room wasn't rented the night before, they maybe willing to check you in early.

And fwiw, if you had flown business class, you still would not have access to the lounges in Suvarnabhumi, as upon landing you have to clear immigration and customs right away, you can not wait in the departure area where the lounges are.

Comment: Sounds like my best option would be to check if my hotel is willing to give me the room if it was not used. Can you suggest any way to take a shower? That would help me a lot to get over jet lag too :P

Comment: You mentioned your hotel being "5 stars", do they have a fitness center or pool?  If so, then perhaps there are shower facilities there you could use before your room is ready.

Comment: Didn't think about that! Great suggestion! I'll definitely look into it